Aruvela Niyogulu (6000 Niyogulu)
What is the origin story of 6000 niyogulu and from when it was existing as I know we are the first in Brahmins to take arms and go for battles and as karnams too after the issues of Arava and Jain karnams with Ganapathi minister of kondaveedu seems. So they say this agnivamsham what is the difference between agnivamsam and 6000 niyogulu.
